# Translate string passed to twig's macro

Tags: theming, 8, i18n-l10n

does Twig provide any way to translate string which is passed to macro? I thought that it would work in similar way to Wordpress translation function where instead of string I just provide the variable. But it does not work.

Here is my macro:

```
{% macro input(type, name, placeholder, value, class) %}
<input type="{{ type|default('text') }}" name="{{ name }}" placeholder="{{ placeholder | t}}" value="{{ value | e }}"
       class="{{ class }}">
{% endmacro %}
```

Then I call it in this way:

```
{{ macro.input('text', 'name', 'Name...') }}
```

I want just to translate the placeholders but when I use | t filter drupal returns the error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: $string ("") must be a string. in Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup->__construct() (line 140 of F:\xampp\htdocs\va\core\lib\Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup.php).
```

I am aware that input is not great example and I should use form API, it's just the easiest to explain. Is there any way of translating strings which are passed to macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The |filter has to be included while calling macro like this:

```
{{ macro.input('text', 'name', 'Name...' | t) }}
```

Comment: Maybe there might be a way to make it work inside the macro, but this is the recommended approach anyway. t should, if at all possible, always be called on the actual string, not on a variable. That allows tolls like potx (which localize.drupal.org uses for example) to extract translatable strings from the files. While localize.drupal.org is only for core/contrib, you might also end up using that tool to create translation files to translate your module for custom code.